# Draggable icon or image button in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to add draggable icon in mobile app which i can move anywhere on screen.

I tried with floating action but no luck.

```
<views:FloatingActionButton HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="End"
            ImageSource="CallHistory.png" 
            x:Name="floCallHistory"
                 ButtonColor="Transparent" 


            Clicked="floCallHistory_Clicked"  BackgroundColor="Transparent" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
            >

                </views:FloatingActionButton>
```

Comment: Try to use the [SfRadialMenu](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfRadialMenu) to achieve this feature. The plugin supports to drag the view in the application. You could google the keyword with **Getting Started with Xamarin Radial Menu (SfRadialMenu)** to check the related tutorial.

Comment: Any free assembly available. Syncfusion are licenced .

Comment: The [Xamarin.Forms.RadialMenu](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.RadialMenu/) plugin also supports the floating action button feature and you could achieve the drag function in custom renderer. Check the related guideline about plugin on github.